# Set InstallerName on the apk, so late i can use getInstallerPackageName()

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I have my app in differents markets and I have it on my web (With a direct download).

I use `getInstallerPackageName()` to determinate from which market it has been downloaded.

What I want is, How I can set a InstallerPackageName on the apk of my web? So when I make `getInstallerPackageName()` it return something like "com.myweb.page".

It will be good if I can set it dynamically so I can set on InstallerName the referer.